# tSQLt.RunAll returns 0 test cases but tSQLt.Run <schema name> works

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I previously had an install of tSQLt on my database, along with some tests.  I used the tSQLt.Uninstall to remove it and then deleted all the tests and the schema's they were in.

I have reinstalled tSQLt and created a new schema and created a bunch of new test stored procs.  When I perform a tSQLt.RunAll I get;

```
+----------------------+
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+

|No|Test Case Name|Result|
+--+--------------+------+
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Summary: 0 test case(s) executed, 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 errored.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run tSQLt.Run Test_DWH_UnitTests I get results.

The tSQLt.RunAll worked against the previous install.

Any help would be very much appreciated. - Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the schema is created using

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass '<schemaname>'
```

rather than just creating the test class using

```
CREATE SCHEMA '<schemaname>'
```

It'll then mark the Schema as a test class.